# Can Arcpy Reconcile Initiate the Interactive Conflict Review?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-server, versioning, reconcile

I'm pretty new to python but trying to hide a lot of the nitty-gritty of creating a grandfathered version and reconciling from my users. I've gotten pretty far, but can't figure out a way for a toolbox script in ArcMap to kick off the interactive conflict review window for my users - is this possible using python and ArcMap?

I can't seem to find any info online about this. I'm using AGS 10.2, python 2.7.
Here is the window I'm trying to initiate (conflict resolution window):  http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#//009300001606000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tested [ReconcileVersions_management](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000015p000000) in data management toolbox? This tool reconciles a version or multiple versions against a target version. It can be used standalone or with python window of ArcMap.

However that tool won't pop up the interactive conflict window. To pop up that window I suggest you to create a python addin (a bottom) and set the callback of the button to the open Conflict Viewer Dialog.

I couldn't find a way to run a builtin command (Open Conflict Viewer Window) from Arcpy.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was using but couldn't figure out a way in Arcpy either. I will look into python addin option, but not sure it's deployable in our situation. I will post further details if I go this route and it works. Thanks!